# Is there method to connect python to online database?

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I want to connect my raspberry pi to an online database and make changes to the records, but I tried serveral time where it gives me errors like "Connection timed out","Access denied for root user using password = yes"

```
import mysql.connector 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="sql106.epizy.com",
  user="epiz_24910878",
  passwd="jianliang176",
  database="epiz_24910878_mydb"

)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


def insertStudentCheckin():
    try:

        sql = "INSERT INTO tblUser (uName,uPW) VALUES (%s,%s)"
        val = (str(2),'absent')
        #insert the check in with card id and today time and date
        #first time is insert so no nid to check the card id value
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)

        mydb.commit()

        print(mycursor.rowcount, "student today record inserted.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
print("hello")
insertStudentCheckin()
print("world")
```

My desired output is that I can insert records to the remote database.

Comment: maybe it needs different user, or you have to add to database new user with your IP, or database is not avaliable for external computers even if you add your IP - it is common method to secure database. Maybe first try with some database editor/viewer like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). If you can access computer (and database) by ssh then you can try to use [ssh tunneling](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/create-an-ssh-tunnel-for-mysql-remote-access/).